# Speed up `strsplit` when possible output are known

Tags: r, performance, reshape2, strsplit, stringr

I have a large data frame with a factor column that I need to divide into three factor columns by splitting up the factor names by a delimiter.  Here is my current approach, which is very slow with a large data frame (sometimes several million rows):

```
data <- readRDS("data.rds")
data.df <- reshape2:::melt.array(data)
head(data.df)
##  Time Location    Class Replicate Population
##1    1        1 LIDE.1.S         1 0.03859605
##2    2        1 LIDE.1.S         1 0.03852957
##3    3        1 LIDE.1.S         1 0.03846853
##4    4        1 LIDE.1.S         1 0.03841260
##5    5        1 LIDE.1.S         1 0.03836147
##6    6        1 LIDE.1.S         1 0.03831485

Rprof("str.out")
cl <- which(names(data.df)=="Class")
Classes <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(data.df$Class), "\\."))
colnames(Classes) <- c("Species", "SizeClass", "Infected")
data.df <- cbind(data.df[,1:(cl-1)],Classes,data.df[(cl+1):(ncol(data.df))])
Rprof(NULL)

head(data.df)
##  Time Location Species SizeClass Infected Replicate Population
##1    1        1    LIDE         1        S         1 0.03859605
##2    2        1    LIDE         1        S         1 0.03852957
##3    3        1    LIDE         1        S         1 0.03846853
##4    4        1    LIDE         1        S         1 0.03841260
##5    5        1    LIDE         1        S         1 0.03836147
##6    6        1    LIDE         1        S         1 0.03831485

summaryRprof("str.out")

$by.self
                 self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"strsplit"            1.34    50.00       1.34     50.00
"<Anonymous>"         1.16    43.28       1.16     43.28
"do.call"             0.04     1.49       2.54     94.78
"unique.default"      0.04     1.49       0.04      1.49
"data.frame"          0.02     0.75       0.12      4.48
"is.factor"           0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75
"match"               0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75
"structure"           0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75
"unlist"              0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75

$by.total
                       total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"do.call"                    2.54     94.78      0.04     1.49
"strsplit"                   1.34     50.00      1.34    50.00
"<Anonymous>"                1.16     43.28      1.16    43.28
"cbind"                      0.14      5.22      0.00     0.00
"data.frame"                 0.12      4.48      0.02     0.75
"as.data.frame.matrix"       0.08      2.99      0.00     0.00
"as.data.frame"              0.08      2.99      0.00     0.00
"as.factor"                  0.08      2.99      0.00     0.00
"factor"                     0.06      2.24      0.00     0.00
"unique.default"             0.04      1.49      0.04     1.49
"unique"                     0.04      1.49      0.00     0.00
"is.factor"                  0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
"match"                      0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
"structure"                  0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
"unlist"                     0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
"[.data.frame"               0.02      0.75      0.00     0.00
"["                          0.02      0.75      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 2.68
```

Is there any way to speed up this operation?  I note that there are a small (<5) number of each of the categories "Species", "SizeClass", and "Infected", and I know what these are in advance.

Notes:

- `stringr::str_split_fixed` performs this task, but not any faster
- The data frame is actually initially generated by calling `reshape::melt` on an array in which `Class` and its associated levels are a dimension.  If there's a faster way to get from there to here, great.
- `data.rds` at http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/3356641/data.rds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should probably offer quite an increase:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data.df)


DT[, c("Species", "SizeClass", "Infected") 
      := as.list(strsplit(Class, "\\.")[[1]]), by=Class ]
```

---

The reasons for the increase:

1. `data.table`  pre allocates memory for columns
2. every column assignment in data.frame reassigns the entirety of the data (data.table in contrast does not)
3. the `by` statement allows you to implement the `strsplit` task once per each unique value.

---

Here is a nice quick method for the whole process.

```
# Save the new col names as a character vector 
newCols <- c("Species", "SizeClass", "Infected") 

# split the string, then convert the new cols to columns
DT[, c(newCols) := as.list(strsplit(as.character(Class), "\\.")[[1]]), by=Class ]
DT[, c(newCols) := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols=newCols]

# remove the old column. This is instantaneous. 
DT[, Class := NULL]

## Have a look: 
DT[, lapply(.SD, class)]
#       Time Location Replicate Population Species SizeClass Infected
# 1: integer  integer   integer    numeric  factor    factor   factor

DT
```

Comment: That is fast!  Though you ned to use `as.character(Class)`. Can you return the columns as factors in the same command?

Comment: You can convert to factor, but do it as a second line after.  Using as.factor in the same call that includes a 'by' argument necessarily slows down the process.

Comment: @NoamRoss, nice catch on the `as.character`.  Updated code plus a few extra steps

Comment: Looking at the answer from @SchaunW, your best increase will probably come from combining data.table with SchaunW's answer.

Comment: I think (3) is probably the main reason for the speedup in this case.

Comment: @hadley, I would guess its #2.  Without profiling, hard to be sure.  If I find some downtime ill test it out.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I think you're overestimating how slow adding a new column to a dataframe is.`f <- function() data.df$y <- 5; microbenchmark(f())`: takes about 35 ms for me.

Comment: @Hadley, you're probably right about (3) being the main reason for the speedup (especially re-reading the OP in that there are only a few unique values).  However, #2 certainly has a real cost when the data is substantial. `data.df` right now is less than 2KB.  Try the same process with, say, a large subset of the flight data. If the data is > 1GB, creating a column will probably be 1 or 2 seconds. Then try it again with `data.table`.  I would guess you would cut that down by about 75~85%.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I'm not disagreeing that data.table is faster, but it's unlikely in general that creating columns is the bottleneck (unless you're doing it in a loop in a naive way)

Answer (score 3):

You could get a decent increase in speed by just extracting the parts of the string you need using `gsub` instead of splitting everything up and trying to put it back together:

```
data <- readRDS("~/Downloads/data.rds")
data.df <- reshape2:::melt.array(data)

# using `strsplit`
system.time({
cl <- which(names(data.df)=="Class")
Classes <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(data.df$Class), "\\."))
colnames(Classes) <- c("Species", "SizeClass", "Infected")
data.df <- cbind(data.df[,1:(cl-1)],Classes,data.df[(cl+1):(ncol(data.df))])
})

user  system elapsed 
3.349   0.062   3.411 

#using `gsub`
system.time({
data.df$Class <- as.character(data.df$Class)
data.df$SizeClass <- gsub("(\\w+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)", "\\2", data.df$Class,
  perl = TRUE)
data.df$Infected  <- gsub("(\\w+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)", "\\3", data.df$Class, 
  perl = TRUE)
data.df$Class  <- gsub("(\\w+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)", "\\1", data.df$Class, 
  perl = TRUE)
})

user  system elapsed 
0.812   0.037   0.848
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a factor, so work on the levels and then map back. Use `fixed=TRUE` in `strsplit`, adjusting to `split="."`.

```
Classes <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(levels(data.df$Class), ".", fixed=TRUE))
colnames(Classes) <- c("Species", "SizeClass", "Infected")
df0 <- as.data.frame(Classes[data.df$Class,], row.names=NA)
cbind(data.df, df0)
```

Comment: Actually a great answer - simple and adds no new dependencies. But the join can be slow with a big data.frame, too, so Ricardo's `data.frame` construct is a better solution for me.

Comment: Oops, meant `data.table` construct, but I can't seem to edit the comment after this long.

Comment: This suggestion sped up my code by an order of magnitude! Thanks!